# How can I have different global parameters for different constraint handlers in SCIP Optimization Suite?

Tags: linear-programming, scip

Say, I have three constraint handlers `ConsHdlr1`, `ConsHdlr2` and `ConsHdlr3` and I want them to have different parameter values, as in `ConsHdlr1`'s minefficacy should be 0.001, `ConsHdlr2`'s should be 0.0001 while `ConsHdlr3`'s is 0.005. I see that there is a `separating/minefficacy = 0.0001` parameter but I assume it applies to all the three constraint handlers. Is there a way to specify parameters for each constraint handler separately? I was hoping to set the value of parameters to my desired value when the cut loop starts and reset it when it ends but I am not sure where to put those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only thing you can do it is check if the cut you generated fulfills the efficacy requirements that you want directly inside your constraint handler and then force the cut into the LP with the correct flag in `SCIPaddRow`.

Comment: I am currently doing that. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: can we limit how many constraints a particular constraint handler can add or should we still do it via efficacy route? (assuming there are more than 1 constraint handler). Can I say specify that this constraint handler can add no more than 30 cuts through out its lifetime.

Comment: There is no existing feature for this, but you can implement this very easily inside your constraint handler, of course. Just add a counter to the `CONSHDLRDATA`

Comment: Thanks! That is clever.